# Looking to create a distance converting class

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class that converts between miles, meters, feet, inches and yards. Supposedly my return statements are not storing any values, I was told that I do not need so many functions and my print function is empty because I could not figure out what to put inside so I long-handed it in main. A plethora of issues, I know, I am looking for guidance. I've been looking at a ton of documentation and am just not getting it - maybe someone can explain in layman terms.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class DistanceConverter { //Class name
    public:
        DistanceConverter() { //Default constructor
            miles_ = 0;
        }
        DistanceConverter(double Miles) { //Overload constructor
            miles_ = Miles;
        }
        //Miles mutators and accessors
        void SetMilesToMeters(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 1609.34;
        }
        double GetMilesFromMeters() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetMilesToInches(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 63360;
        }
        double GetMilesFromInches() {
            return miles_;
        }


        void SetMilesToFeet(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 5280;
        }
        double GetMilesFromFeet() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetMilesToYards(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 1760;
        }
        double GetMilesFromYards() {
            return miles_;
        }

        //Yards mutators and accessors
        void SetYardsToMiles(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 1760;
        }
        double GetYardsFromMiles() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetYardsToFeet(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 3;
        }
        double GetYardsFromFeet() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetYardsToInches(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 36;
        }
        double GetYardsFromInches() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetYardsToMeters(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 0.9144;
        }
        double GetYardsFromMeters() {
            return miles_;
        }

        //Feet mutators and accessors
        void SetFeetToMiles(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 5280;
        }
        double GetFeetFromMiles() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetFeetToYards(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 3;
        }
        double GetFeetFromYards() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetFeetToInches(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 12;
        }
        double GetFeetFromInches() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetFeetToMeters(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 0.3048;
        }
        double GetFeetFromMeters() {
            return miles_;
        }

        //Inches mutators and accessors
        void SetInchesToMiles(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 63360;
        }
        double GetInchesFromMiles() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetInchesToYards(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 36;
        }
        double GetInchesFromYards() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetInchesToMeters(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles * 0.0254;
        }
        double GetInchesFromMeters() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetInchesToFeet(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 12;
        }
        double GetInchesFromFeet() {
            return miles_;
        }

        //Meters mutators and accessors
        void SetMetersToMiles(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 1609.34;
        }
        double GetMetersFromMiles() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetMetersToYards(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 0.9144;
        }
        double GetMetersFromYards() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetMetersToFeet(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 0.3048;
        }
        double GetMetersFromFeet() {
            return miles_;
        }

        void SetMetersToInches(double Miles) {
            miles_ = Miles / 0.0254;
        }
        double GetMetersFromInches() {
            return miles_;
        }

        //Print function
        void PrintDistances() {}

    private:
        double miles_; 
};


int main() {
    //Mile objects
    DistanceConverter MileToMeter;
    DistanceConverter MileToInch;
    DistanceConverter MileToFeet;
    DistanceConverter MileToYard;
    //Yard objects
    DistanceConverter YardToMile;
    DistanceConverter YardToFeet;
    DistanceConverter YardToInch;
    DistanceConverter YardToMeter;
    //Feet Objects
    DistanceConverter FeetToMile;
    DistanceConverter FeetToYard;
    DistanceConverter FeetToInch;
    DistanceConverter FeetToMeter;
    //Inch objects
    DistanceConverter InchToMile;
    DistanceConverter InchToYard;
    DistanceConverter InchToMeter;
    DistanceConverter InchToFeet;
    //Meter Objects
    DistanceConverter MeterToMile;
    DistanceConverter MeterToYard;
    DistanceConverter MeterToFeet;
    DistanceConverter MeterToInch;

    //Miles to X conversions
    MileToMeter.SetMilesToMeters(1);
    cout<<"Miles to meters: " << MileToMeter.GetMilesFromMeters() << endl;
    MileToMeter.PrintDistances();

    MileToInch.SetMilesToInches(1);
    cout<<"Miles to inches: " << MileToInch.GetMilesFromInches() << endl;
    MileToInch.PrintDistances();

    MileToFeet.SetMilesToFeet(1);
    cout<<"Miles to feet: " << MileToFeet.GetMilesFromFeet() << endl;
    MileToFeet.PrintDistances();

    MileToYard.SetMilesToYards(1);
    cout<<"Miles to yards: " << MileToYard.GetMilesFromYards() << endl;
    MileToYard.PrintDistances();

    //Yards to X conversions
    YardToMile.SetYardsToMiles(10.5);
    cout<<"Yards to miles: " << YardToMile.GetYardsFromMiles() << endl;
    YardToMile.PrintDistances();

    YardToFeet.SetYardsToFeet(20);
    cout<<"Yards to feet: " << YardToFeet.GetYardsFromFeet() << endl;
    YardToMile.PrintDistances();

    YardToInch.SetYardsToInches(5.3);
    cout<<"Yards to inches: " << YardToInch.GetYardsFromInches() << endl;
    YardToMile.PrintDistances();

    YardToMeter.SetYardsToMeters(11);
    cout<<"Yards to meters: " << YardToMeter.GetYardsFromMeters() << endl;
    YardToMile.PrintDistances();

    //Feet to X conversions
    FeetToMile.SetFeetToMiles(16);
    cout<<"Feet to miles: " << FeetToMile.GetFeetFromMiles() << endl;
    YardToFeet.PrintDistances();

    FeetToYard.SetFeetToYards(16);
    cout<<"Feet to yards: " << FeetToYard.GetFeetFromYards() << endl;
    FeetToYard.PrintDistances();

    FeetToInch.SetFeetToInches(2);
    cout<<"Feet to inches: " << FeetToInch.GetFeetFromInches() << endl;
    FeetToInch.PrintDistances();

    FeetToMeter.SetFeetToMeters(11);
    cout<<"Feet to meters: " << FeetToMeter.GetFeetFromMeters() << endl;
    FeetToMeter.PrintDistances();

    //Inches to X conversions
    InchToMile.SetInchesToMiles(100);
    cout<<"Inches to miles: " << InchToMile.GetInchesFromMiles() << endl;
    InchToMile.PrintDistances();

    InchToYard.SetInchesToYards(15);
    cout<<"Inches to yards: " << InchToYard.GetInchesFromYards() << endl;
    InchToYard.PrintDistances();

    InchToMeter.SetInchesToMeters(55);
    cout<<"Inches to meters: " << InchToMeter.GetInchesFromMeters() << endl;
    InchToMeter.PrintDistances();

    InchToFeet.SetInchesToFeet(12);
    cout<<"Inches to feet: " << InchToFeet.GetInchesFromFeet() << endl;
    InchToFeet.PrintDistances();

    //Meter to X conversions
    MeterToMile.SetMetersToMiles(1);
    cout<<"Meters to miles: " << MeterToMile.GetMetersFromMiles() << endl;
    MeterToMile.PrintDistances();

    MeterToYard.SetMetersToYards(100);
    cout<<"Meters to yards: " << MeterToYard.GetMetersFromYards() << endl;
    MeterToYard.PrintDistances();

    MeterToFeet.SetMetersToFeet(100);
    cout<<"Meters to feet: " << MeterToFeet.GetMetersFromFeet() << endl;
    MeterToFeet.PrintDistances();

    MeterToInch.SetMetersToInches(100);
    cout<<"Meters to inches: " << MeterToInch.GetMetersFromInches() << endl;
    MeterToInch.PrintDistances();

}
```

Comment: Dunno why I always get down voted for asking questions..

Comment: you are missing a specific question; we can't answer something that doesn't have a question. also, you seem to have working code; you can post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for recommendations for improving your code

Comment: Sorry. My specific questions are: 1. How can I do this using less functions 2.  Why wouldn't the return statements be storing any values? And forget about the print function because I think the print function will make more sense once I can get 1 and 2 solved.

Comment: You probably need to read [ask]. Stackoverflow is not suitable for every type of programming-related question. For instance, it is especially not intended for tutoring and guidance.

Comment: You should **edit** your post with your questions; don't place into comments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a `class` or `struct` for each unit.

In your design, there is nothing stopping me from calling miles to meters using a number in feet.

By using classes as the unit type, you can write conversion methods (operators) so that the *compiler* will call the appropriate methods based on the variable type (in this case, the unit).

For example:

```
struct Feet
{
   unsigned int value;
};
class Miles;
class Meters;
Feet Convert_From(const Meters& m);
Meters Convert_From(const Miles& mi);
```

The compiler will choose the appropriate conversion function based on the variable type.

**Edit 1: Constructors**
You could also use constructors for the conversion:

```
struct Inches
{
  unsigned int value;
};
struct Feet
{
  unsigned int value;
  Feet(unsigned int f)
    : value(f)
  { ; }
  Feet(const Inches& in)
  {
    value = in/12;
  }
};

//...
Inches in;
in.value = 24;
Feet f(in);
cout << f.value << endl;
```

Comment: `double` seems more appropriate that `int` due to rounding conversion.

Comment: Even if I like strong type, there, it would not reduce methods count.

Comment: The solution I presented is not for reducing methods count, but for robustness and correctness.  So, why do you care about how many methods there are?  (Most likely, one for each conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea of how to achieve this with a pattern that is simpler and easier to use.

Note that it only performs `Miles <-> Feet <-> Inches` conversions, and the rest (meters, yard, etc.) are left as an exercise to you.

Most notably it makes use of `static` methods so that you do not need to initialize new objects just to perform a simple conversion. It also only has a single `public` method from which all conversions are performed from.

This allows for more flexibility and is also easier for the user.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class DistanceType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Inches,
    Feet,
    Miles
};

class DistanceConverter
{
public:

    static double Convert(double const value, DistanceType const from, DistanceType const to)
    {
        switch(from)
        {
        case DistanceType::Miles:
            return ConvertMiles(value, to);

        case DistanceType::Feet:
            return ConvertFeet(value, to);

        case DistanceType::Inches:
            return ConvertInches(value, to);

        default:
            return value;
        }
    }

protected:

private:

    static double ConvertMiles(double const value, DistanceType const to)
    {
        switch(to)
        {
        case DistanceType::Feet:
            return (value * MilesToFeet());

        case DistanceType::Inches:
            return (value * MilesToFeet()) * FeetToInches();

        default:
            return value;
        }
    }

    static double ConvertFeet(double const value, DistanceType const to)
    {
        switch(to)
        {
        case DistanceType::Miles:
            return (value / MilesToFeet());

        case DistanceType::Inches:
            return (value * FeetToInches());

        default:
            return value;
        }
    }

    static double ConvertInches(double const value, DistanceType const to)
    {
        switch(to)
        {
        case DistanceType::Miles:
            return (value / FeetToInches()) / MilesToFeet();

        case DistanceType::Feet:
            return (value / FeetToInches());

        default:
            return value;
        }
    }

    static constexpr double MilesToFeet() { return 5280.0; };
    static constexpr double FeetToInches() { return 12.0; };
};

int main()
{
    const double miles        = 5.0;
    const double milesToFeet  = DistanceConverter::Convert(miles,        DistanceType::Miles,  DistanceType::Feet);
    const double feetToInches = DistanceConverter::Convert(milesToFeet,  DistanceType::Feet,   DistanceType::Inches);
    const double inchesToFeet = DistanceConverter::Convert(feetToInches, DistanceType::Inches, DistanceType::Feet);
    const double feetToMiles  = DistanceConverter::Convert(inchesToFeet, DistanceType::Feet,   DistanceType::Miles);

    std::cout << miles << " miles is: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << milesToFeet << " feet" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << feetToInches << " inches" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << feetToInches << " inches is: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << inchesToFeet << " feet" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << feetToMiles << " miles" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
5 miles is:
    26400 feet
    316800 inches

316800 inches is:
    26400 feet
    5 miles
```

Note that I use the result of the first conversion (miles to inches) to verify the results of the second (inches to miles).

Comment: Thank you I understand what you're trying to explain but my intro c++ class hasn't gone over switch/case statements yet

Answer (score 0):

To reduce function from `n²` to `2 * n`, use one main dimension for your class, and provide helper conversions from and to this dimension:

```
class Distance
{
private:
    double meters_;
    Distance(double meters) : meters_(meters) {}
public:
    static Distance FromMeters(double meters) { return { meters }; }
    static Distance FromMiles(double miles) { return { 1609.34 * miles }; }
    static Distance FromInches(double inches) { return { 0.0254 * inches }; }
    static Distance FromFeet(double feet) { return { 0.3048 * feet }; }
    static Distance FromYards(double yards) { return { 0.9144 * yards} ; }

    double ToMeters() const { return meters_; }
    double ToMiles() const { return meters_ / 1609.34; }
    double ToInches() const { return meters_ / 0.0254; }
    double ToFeet() const { return meters_ / 0.3048; }
    double ToYards() const { return meters_ / 0.9144; }

};
```

And then use it that way

```
std::cout << "Miles to inches: " << Distance::FromMiles(1).ToInches() << std::endl;
```